# Table in two column - line breaking

Tags: tables, line-breaking, two-column

I would like to have breaks in in that table. Could you please help me out?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn,conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,margin=3cm}
\usepackage{caption}% <-- added
\captionsetup[table]{skip = 3pt}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,longtable,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}% <-- added
\usepackage{ltablex}% <-- added
\usepackage{siunitx}% <-- added
\usepackage{caption}% <-- added
\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{7in}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttablex}

\flushbottom

\begin{document}
\section{INTRODUCTION}
This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section.

Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. 

\begin{table}[!htb]
\captionsetup{size=footnotesize}
\caption{Year Wise Treatment Frequencies} \label{tab:freq}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX compute intercolumn whitespace
\footnotesize\centering
This table provides the frequencies.

\smallskip 
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}rcccr}
\toprule
  Year  & Nones& Option  1 & Option 2 & Total \\
\midrule
  2001& 126   & 16    & 2     & This section is the introduction section. \\
  2002& 114   & 9     & 4     & 127 \\
  2003& 115   & 7     & 1     & 123 \\
  2004& 114   & 6     & 4     & 124 \\
  2005& 104   & 5     & 8     & 117 \\
  2006& 96    & 3     & 6     & 105 \\
  2007& 93    & 2     & 4     & 99 \\
  2008& 93    & 2     & 2     & 97 \\
  2009& 85    & 2     & 11    & 98 \\
  2010& 83    & 0     & 7     & 90 \\
  2011& 74    & 0     & 12    & 86 \\
  \midrule
  Total & 1,097 & 52    & 61    & 1,210 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction.This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. 

Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction.
Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. 

Here is a the text about the introduction.Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction.
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I compile your document, I get a different output:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEvo6.png

Comment: What kind of "breaks"  are you referring to?

Comment: the image shows that your table is being forced wide by a misplaced text "this section is.." but as that text is not in your example code, it means the image is from another document and hard to correct code not shown. Please always post the output image from the code posted.

Comment: Sorry for that. Now the code works and its the example I screenshoted. I would like to get any column forced to break lines. This is just an example for the last column. In my document I have forced the table to be as wide as the column is with {\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}rcccr} but I don't know how to to a line breaking except of changing it like this {\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}rcccp{3cm}} but this is not working for all my columns. Any other idea?

Comment: Remove the `ltablex` package and use `\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{rcccX}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**

Removing `\usepackage{ltablex}`.

Using `tabularx`  for the table. (It looks better with the last column centered).

[image: cx]

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \captionsetup{size=footnotesize}
    \caption{Year Wise Treatment Frequencies} \label{tab:freq}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX compute intercolumn whitespace
    \footnotesize\centering
    This table provides the frequencies.
    
    \smallskip 
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{8pt}}lccc>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
        \toprule
        Year  & Nones& Option  1 & Option 2 & Total \\
        \midrule
        2001& 126   & 16    & 2     & This section is the introduction section. \\
        2002& 114   & 9     & 4     & 127 \\
        2003& 115   & 7     & 1     & 123 \\
        2004& 114   & 6     & 4     & 124 \\
        2005& 104   & 5     & 8     & 117 \\
        2006& 96    & 3     & 6     & 105 \\
        2007& 93    & 2     & 4     & 99 \\
        2008& 93    & 2     & 2     & 97 \\
        2009& 85    & 2     & 11    & 98 \\
        2010& 83    & 0     & 7     & 90 \\
        2011& 74    & 0     & 12    & 86 \\
        \midrule
        Total & 1,097 & 52    & 61    & 1,210 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

**Option 2**

Removing `\usepackage{ltablex}`.

Adding `\usepackage{makecell}` to the preamble (to be able to use `\\` inside the cell).

Using `tabularx`  for the table.

Note that now the first row is vertically centered and cell with  the long text is left aligned, thanks to the command  `\renewcommand\cellalign{lc}`

[image: m]

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \renewcommand\cellalign{lc} % added <<<
    \captionsetup{size=footnotesize}
    \caption{Year Wise Treatment Frequencies} \label{tab:freq}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX compute intercolumn whitespace
    \footnotesize\centering
    This table provides the frequencies.
    
    \smallskip 
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcccc}
        \toprule
        Year  & Nones& Option  1 & Option 2 & Total \\
        \midrule
        2001& 126   & 16    & 2     & \makecell{This section is the\\ introduction section.} \\% changed
        2002& 114   & 9     & 4     & 127 \\
        2003& 115   & 7     & 1     & 123 \\
        2004& 114   & 6     & 4     & 124 \\
        2005& 104   & 5     & 8     & 117 \\
        2006& 96    & 3     & 6     & 105 \\
        2007& 93    & 2     & 4     & 99 \\
        2008& 93    & 2     & 2     & 97 \\
        2009& 85    & 2     & 11    & 98 \\
        2010& 83    & 0     & 7     & 90 \\
        2011& 74    & 0     & 12    & 86 \\
        \midrule
        Total & 1,097 & 52    & 61    & 1,210 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

**Option 3**

Removing `\usepackage{ltablex}`.

Using `tabular*`.

Nesting a tabular inside

`\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} This section is the \\introduction section.\end{tabular}`

[image: n]

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \captionsetup{size=footnotesize}
    \caption{Year Wise Treatment Frequencies} \label{tab:freq}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX compute intercolumn whitespace
    \footnotesize\centering
    This table provides the frequencies.
    
    \smallskip 
    \begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcccc}
        \toprule
        Year  & Nones& Option  1 & Option 2 & Total \\
        \midrule
        2001& 126   & 16    & 2     & \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} This section is the \\introduction section.\end{tabular} \\
        2002& 114   & 9     & 4     & 127 \\
        2003& 115   & 7     & 1     & 123 \\
        2004& 114   & 6     & 4     & 124 \\
        2005& 104   & 5     & 8     & 117 \\
        2006& 96    & 3     & 6     & 105 \\
        2007& 93    & 2     & 4     & 99 \\
        2008& 93    & 2     & 2     & 97 \\
        2009& 85    & 2     & 11    & 98 \\
        2010& 83    & 0     & 7     & 90 \\
        2011& 74    & 0     & 12    & 86 \\
        \midrule
        Total & 1,097 & 52    & 61    & 1,210 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```